# How to use dispatch_async_f?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, function, grand-central-dispatch

The function that I want queued takes no parameters. What do I pass in as `paramContext`? Passing in NULL generates the compile error "Invalid use of void expression". I do not want to add a parameter to my function just to make it compile - how do I make this work?

Mac OS X Snowleopard, Xcode 3.2.6 with Objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the function somehow. The easiest way is actually to use `dispatch_async()` instead, as in

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ myFunc() });
```

Answer (score 11):

While you can just pass `0`/`NULL` for the context argument, `dispatch_async_f()` takes `void (*)(void*)` as the function parameter, you can't pass it a function that takes no arguments.

You need to either change your function to take a `void*` parameter:

```
void func(void*) {}
```

... or, if you can't, wrap it:

```
void orig(void) {}
void wrapper(void*) { orig(); }

// ...
dispatch_async_f(queue, 0, &wrapper);
```