# Grand Central Dispatch without blocks

Tags: ios, macos, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

Is it possible to use GCD without blocks? Is there a way to use GCD using _f variant as mikeash says in his [post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/gcd-is-not-blocks-blocks-are-not-gcd.html#comment-d04cc5ec2e30fc1d4a0ce11548071d63). I searched around and there is no proof for either sides. is it possible or impossible.

If its doable please give an example.

/Selvin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible! By `_f` variants Mike just mean set of `GCD` functions with `_f` suffix. They are alternatives for usual `GCD` functions but can accept a user defined function as a parameter instead of blocks. There are plenty of them:

```
dispatch_async_f
dispatch_sync_f
dispatch_after_f
dispatch_apply_f
dispatch_group_async_f
dispatch_group_notify_f
dispatch_set_finalizer_f
dispatch_barrier_async_f
dispatch_barrier_sync_f
dispatch_source_set_registration_handler_f
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler_f
dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f
```

They accept `dispatch_function_t` parameter (instead of usual `dispatch_block_t`) which is defined as follows:

`typedef void (*dispatch_function_t)(void*)`.

As you see it can accept any user parameter and also a function because of `*void` pointer. So you can even use `dispatch_function_t` with function that have no arguments - you can just write a wrapper function like so:

```
void func(void) {
  //do any calculations you want here
    }
void wrapper_function(void*) { func(); }
dispatch_async_f(queue, 0, &wrapper_function);
```

Or pass a function pointer as a parameter. Or on the contrary you can use `_f` variants of GCD functions with user defined functions which can accept any number of arguments via the varargs (variadic functions) - just write a function wrapper for it also as above. As you see `_f` functions is rather a powerful mechanism and you are not limited only with blocks without parameters for GCD but can use usual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as stated on the article:

> You can use GCD without blocks, via the _f variants provided for every
>   GCD function that takes a block

If you look at the [GCD documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) you can check the variants. If you need a quick example [there are many on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320142/how-to-use-dispatch-async-f):