# iPhone programming: how to execute code in the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can we write the code to run in the background in iPhone Application, same as the `Service` OR `AsyncTask` in Android?

Comment: refer this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: See Background Execution and Multitasking https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Answer (score 5):

iOS platform since iOS 3.0 fully supports multithreading and background code execution. There are several ways you can achieve this (thread which is not a main UI thread I will call a background thread). I'll try to cover all:

1. [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)- you should use when you want to control you backgound thread fully. You can control thread prioriies with `setThreadPriority:`, set thread stack size, names and etc. `NSThread` is just a Cocoa wrapper around the [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) which you can also use, but it is an old way and I even won't consider it. For example and guide on how to work with pthreads or `NSThread` look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html
2. `- (void)performSelectorInBackground :`one of the simplest ways. It just runs the specified method on a new background thread: simple and solid. For docs look here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:

   ```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(makeNetworkRequestOrWhateverInBackground:)
                  withObject:someArgument];
   ```

   It is identical to `NSThread` way with `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(makeNetworkRequestOrWhateverInBackground:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`

   But I want to **emphasize** that it is now `not` a good way of doing background stuff. `performSelector` has a lot of downsides: it’s pretty slow (creates a `NSThread` object dynamically, memory overhead, because of storing thread stacks, and so on and so forth), passing data to the method, you want to keep in the background is a real pain in the ass (you have to wrap it up in the `withObject` parameter, or make global in your object and global data is a bad thing). Apple also recommends to use `GCD` instead of threads and therefore `performSelectorInBackground`, look e.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1). So the third option is what you really need.
3. [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html) - grand central dispatch - is a mainstream technology now. A lot of different third party libs use it like `AFNetworking` (therefore libraries built on top of `AFNetworking` such as `RestKit`). I think you will use this method of multithreading very often. If  you just want to parallelize some simple task, make some network call asynchronously, fetch data from the `Core Data`, etc. you should use `GCD`. This technology is beautiful when combines with [Objective-C blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) (and it was designed for usage with them) but you are not only restricted with blocks, you can use it also with regular functions with [f-variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811414/grand-central-dispatch-without-blocks/17813039#17813039) of GCD functions. A lot of beautiful Objective-C frameworks is built on top GCD. Simple example of usage:

   ```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      [self makeNetworkRequestOrWhateverInBackground];
   });
   ```
4. [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) is a higher abstract level of simple threads. An `NSOperationQueue` object is a queue that handles objects of the `NSOperation` class type which represents a single task, including both the data and the code related to the task. It abstracts the thread concept to operation concept. You can make subclassing, create complex operations dependency graphs, make cancellation and so on and so forth. It supports a number of other higher-level semantics and concepts. Also look at [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) framework - a very interesting implementation and wrapper for all this stuff from Parse and Facebook. `NSOperation` concept IMO is an Apple way of dealing with task-based parallelism, which means that you design your algorithms in terms of "tasks" (work to be done) instead of the specifics of threads and cores. For theory and examples of `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` look for good tutorials [here](http://www.lextech.com/2012/09/nsoperation-theory-and-concepts/) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues).